# dime magazines -- what are those exactly?

Tags: meaning

Source: [C For Dummies, 2nd Edition](https://books.google.ru/books/about/C_For_Dummies.html?id=ruPPRwBYdjIC&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Computers are all about input and output — the old I/O of days gone by,
>   what the pioneers once sang about. The wimminfolk would want to dance
>   real slow. Maybe cry. It was a sentimental thing, y’all — something that fancy, dooded-up city slickers read about in **dime magazines**.

What are those exactly?

Comment: Wow! That's a pretty tough text for a learner to tackle! I assume the pun on **I/O** passed you by (cowboys used to sing "Yippee-aye-oh!"), and it even took me a moment to register *dooded-up = duded-up = dressed in fancy style, as a dude)*. I think the writer is getting a bit carried away with his smartass phrasing, but *dime magazines* just means downmarket / cheap throwaway publications pandering to trivial niche/nerd interests (trainspotting, coin collecting, early home computers, etc.).

Comment: ...note that in *British* English we had [***penny dreadfuls***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_dreadful) long before *dime magazines* in the US, but arguably they were more a reference to the format/price rather than the *content* (many Dickens novels were published in that form, for example).

Comment: This is the lingo of the stereotypical 19th-century cowboy or pioneer who had gone west.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed - a search on "dime magazines" shows a lot of references that use the phrase, but not a good explanation of what they are (cheap publications for mass consumption). You might find this reference to "dime magazines" interesting - [College librarian compiles guide to global pulp fiction](http://www.chron.com/neighborhood/spring/news/article/College-librarian-compiles-guide-to-global-pulp-6946772.php)

Comment: Seconding @Colleen. It's virtually impossible to understand these things from a dictionary. If you have a dictionary for puns, enlighten us please.

Comment: I'm all for attempting to make reading about and learning coding more interesting, but good grief, that author needs to pull his/her head in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference to *dime magazine* is somewhat obscure, but refers to inexpensive magazines of low-quality printing and lower-quality writing aimed at the mass market that were popular from the late 19th to the mid-20th century, nowadays more commonly known as *[pulp magazines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_magazine)*, which printed *pulp fiction*.

[image: Cover of Wild West Weekly, 1908, from the Baylor University Texas Collection]

The author's reference to *pioneers* is a bizarre sidetrack referring to *[American pioneers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_pioneer)*, i.e. the 19th century migrants to the frontier, what are now the the Midwestern and Western United States. But he is not referring to the historical figures so much as certain tropes of the Old West and of rural people as you might have seen in Western films or television, hence the use of [eye dialect](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/eye-dialect) and old-fashioned or rustic diction (e.g. *wimminfolk* rather than *womenfolk* rather than simply *women*). *Dime magazine* is part of this bad affectation, like *dooded-up city slickers* and *y'all*, as a term that the author imagines those pioneers would use.

The author is attempting to be funny, but to inject my personal opinion, he fails. This is needlessly silly on top of being ahistorical.

---

A *dime magazine* (like a *dime novel*, *[dime Western](http://chronicle.uchicago.edu/970417/westerns.shtml)*, *[dime museum](http://cultureandcommunication.org/deadmedia/index.php/Dime_Museums)*, and so on) was originally just a magazine that sold for a *[dime](https://www.usmint.gov/mint_programs/circulatingCoins/?action=CircDime)*, that is, 10¢ ($0.10), but later referred to magazines which printed serialized *dime Westerns*.

One of the oldest denominations of U.S. currency, the dime takes its name from a now-obsolete sense of *dime* meaning *one-tenth*, but being so old and physically distinct (as the smallest and thinnest coin), has found its way into a large number of figurative meanings and use in expressions from *five-and-dime store* to *turn on a dime* to *not worth one thin dime*. The terms *dime novel*, *dime Western*, and so on are no longer common, however, as the medium has essentially died out.

The *dime Western* was a genre of sensationalist stories of violent and untamed frontier life that originated with the 1860 *[Malaeska, The Indian Wife of the White Hunter](https://archive.org/details/04278299.1604.emory.edu)* by Ann Stephens. The cover price of only 10¢ was made possible by new materials, printing techniques, and distribution networks. As daily wages at the time were about $1/day, this was entertainment that was accessible even to unskilled workers. But because these novels were printed on cheap stock, were poorly regarded if at all by the literary world, and catered to [lower-class tastes](http://web.stanford.edu/dept/SUL/library/prod/depts/dp/pennies/home.html), the term *dime Western* or *[dime novel](https://www.loc.gov/exhibits/treasures/tri015.html)* took on a pejorative sense as something low-brow and unintellectual. The earliest mention of the term in the *Corpus of Historical American English* is from the *Atlantic Monthly* in 1867, and the disdain is evident:

> Who could preach a sermon that would hold attentive the man saturated with Buckle, Mill, Spencer, Thackeray, Emerson, Humboldt, and Agassiz, and [also] the man whose only literary recreation is the dime novel?

The OED, similarly attests to

> 1882 *Cent. Mag.* 25 212/1   You are as bad as a dime novel.

Later in the 19th century, the primary format for the dime Western changed from short novel to serials, often titled *libraries*, which became the [pulp magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_magazine), and prices changed to suit.

But the negative association of *dime* persisted, and even though the magazines were priced from 5–25¢, the *dime magazine* as a concept remained. And lo, the *Methodist Magazine and Review*, Vol. 59 (1904) [laments](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lb8QAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3) of *The Pilgrim's Progress*,

> The sensation novel, the daily paper, the dime magazine, have crowded this better reading out.

The trans-Pond equivalent seems to have been the *penny dreadful* (as FumbleFingers noted in a comment), otherwise the *penny awful*, *penny horrible*, and *[shilling shocker](http://www.britannica.com/art/shilling-shocker)*.